# Object not being detected by the garbage collector even after all members are freed. Does TcpClient have anything to do with this?

Tags: c#

I know posting long walls of code is bad, but this problem seems like a 'skim over and see something' kind of problem.

I have a class called Client which contains all the goodies for what I need with a TcpClient.
It runs on it's own thread and uses a killSwitch variable triggered by Dispose() when called.

My problem is that even after Dispose is called and the reference to the object is lost, the object still isn't caught by the GC and is not deleted.

Example of how I have tested creation/deletion of object:

```
private void TESTButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcp = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
    tcp.Connect("127.0.0.1",3005);
    Client c = new Client(tcp, this);
}
```

The class definition:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace v1_GameServer.GameServer
{
    public class Client : IDisposable
    {
        private Boolean gotCommunicatedInfo = false;
        private String username = "";
        private String password = "";
        private String ipAddress;

        private GameServerWindow window;

        private Boolean isDead;

        private static Int32 BUFF_SIZE = 1000;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
        private TcpClient connection;
        private NetworkStream stream;

        private Boolean thisThread_killSwitch = false;
        private readonly Thread thisThread;

        private List<object> packages = new List<object>();
        private object packages_lock = new object();

        private Client()
        { }

        public Client(TcpClient _connection, GameServerWindow win)
        {
            connection = _connection;
            stream = connection.GetStream();
            window = win;

            ipAddress = ((IPEndPoint)connection.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();

            isDead = false;

            thisThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(HandleConnection));
            thisThread.Start();

            window.Post("+Client : " + ipAddress);
        }

        ~Client()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TEST!");
            if (window != null)
                window.Post("-Client : " + ipAddress);
        }

        public void HandleConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                while (!thisThread_killSwitch && !isDead)
                {
                    int numBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, BUFF_SIZE);
                    if (numBytes > sizeof(Int32)) //Big enough to hold at least a type of message.
                    {
                        object newPackage = Package_Reader.ReadPackage(buffer, numBytes);

                        if (gotCommunicatedInfo == false)
                        {
                            if (newPackage is Package_Login_s)
                            {
                                username = ((Package_Login_s)newPackage).username;
                                password = ((Package_Login_s)newPackage).password;
                                gotCommunicatedInfo = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                throw new InvalidOperationException("Received a package that was not login info from a new Client.");
                            }
                        }
                        else //(communicatedInfo == true)
                        {
                            lock (packages_lock)
                            {
                                if (newPackage != null)
                                    packages.Add(newPackage);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (numBytes == 0)
                    {
                        Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
            {
                window.Post(ManagerForm.post_CLIENT_ERROR + "Client disconnected.");
                isDead = true;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                window.Post(ManagerForm.post_CLIENT_ERROR + e.ToString());
                isDead = true;
            }
        }

        public object GetPackage()
        {
            lock (packages_lock)
            {
                if (packages.Count > 0)
                {
                    object pac = packages[packages.Count - 1];
                    packages.RemoveAt(packages.Count - 1);
                    return pac;
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
        }

        public String GetUsername()
        {
            return (String)username.Clone();
        }

        public String GetPassword()
        {
            return (String)password.Clone();
        }

        public Boolean GetGotCommunicatedInfo()
        {
            return gotCommunicatedInfo;
        }

        public Boolean GetIsDead()
        {
            return isDead;
        }

        public String GetIP()
        {
            return (String)ipAddress.Clone();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            thisThread_killSwitch = true;
            isDead = true;
            stream.Dispose();
            stream.Close();
            connection.Close();
            stream = null;
            connection = null;
            window = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not implemented the `IDisposable` pattern on your `Client` class correctly.  The pattern you should implement is this:

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;

    ~Foo()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // Dispose of managed resources
            }

            // Dispose of unmanaged resources

            _disposed = true;
        }       
    }
}
```

This way, regardless of whether `Dispose()` is called or not, the `TcpClient` instance will eventually be tidied up and not cause a resource leak.

Comment: I just implemented this and I'm putting a "MessageBox.Show("HELLO!");" in the destructor. Is there any reason why the destructor wouldn't be called even if it was (edit->) caught by the GC?

Comment: In C#, calling Dispose is not a guarantee the destructor will be called. The destructor will be called when a garbage collection occurs, which may be now, in a minute, in an hour or never..

Comment: Either it hasn't been picked up by a generation of the GC yet (or it still thinks it's alive somewhere), or something else is supressing it's finalisation.

Another possibility is that because you're creating an object but never using it that the compiler has optimised that call away and it never actually happens.

It's also a bad idea to use Windows Forms in the finalizer.  The finalizer runs on its own special thread and may cause thread-context issues when calling UI code.